# TS - Overload Function Signature returned by Factory fn

Tags: typescript, types

I have an high order function which returns a function, and,
for brevity, let's imagine something like that:

```js
function factory() {
  return function baz(payload: { [key: string]: {} }): 'hello' {

    return 'hello';
  }
}

const foo = factory();
```

now, `foo` is the function `baz` which has an argument signature like this (very generic):

```js
interface payload {
  [key: string] : {}
}
```

What I need to do is to overload that signature for `foo` only, to have a more precise signature (desired):

```js
function foo(payload: {id: string}) {}
```

**How can I achieve that?**

Comment: You mean: `const foo = factory() as (payload: {id: string}) => 'hello';` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

```
function factory<P extends { [key: string]: {}}>() {
  return function baz(payload: P): 'hello' {
    return 'hello';
  }
}

const foo = factory<{id: string}>(); // OK
const bar = factory<number>(); // Error
```

Comment: this could suit, I want that `payload` **must always be** and object `{ [key: string]: {}}`. I just want to add a way to describe payload properties. Any idea?